# Flash / flex audio echo cancellation not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, audio

I get a strong echo from anyone with speakers, headsets don't cause it.

I am following all these suggestions http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/acoustic-echo-cancellation.html and experimented with all the settings.  I'm using RTMP.

I tried a couple 3rd party audio chat apps and they had echos too.  Maybe they were built before EC was part of flash.

Are there any 3rd party audio chat apps online with no echo?  Send me a url.

Any other ideas?

Thanks,
Ken